# Where would I find Google IME for Marathi language?

Tags: 12.10, google

I need to type in Marathi on Ubuntu. Where would I find Google IME for Marathi language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no Google IME in Ubuntu for Marathi. But if you want you can add a full fledged devnagiri keyboard. It takes a while to remember the new keyboard but once you have learnt it you no longer need Google IME. Below is the procedure to add Marathi keyboard.
Go to settings/keyboard layout/ then press the '+' icon on the bottom and search for 'Indian' keyboard layout. You can now switch between Marathi and English using the keyboard icon on the top.

Answer (score 1):

`All settings` -> `Text Entry` -> `(+)add Marathi (KaGaPa phonetic)`. Done.

Switch to next source using: <kbd>Super(Windows)</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Switch to previous source using: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>$uper</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>